# Square root theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is:  $\sqrt{x^3y}$.  It's not clear to me why when I take out the $x^2$ that I must put an absolute value around it, since when x remains ***inside*** the square root there is an automatic domain restriction of x being non-negative. I would think that this domain restriction eliminates the need for absolute value bars.

I can see that if there is no x remaining in the square root that I must include the absolute value bars, but unclear why if an x remains inside.

Can someone help me see this?

Comment: What if $y <0$ ?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and $\sqrt{x^3 y}=\sqrt{x^2 \cdot x y}=\sqrt{x^2} \sqrt{x y}=|x| \sqrt{x y}$.

Comment: Yes, I thought this might be the case.  Does that mean that if there had been no y remaining inside the square root, then it would have eliminated the need for the absolute value?

Comment: In this case, yes. However check that you understand why you need the absolute value if you are considering $\sqrt{x^4y}$.

Comment: what if the question is $\sqrt(x^3)$  Doesn't the x remaining inside the square root negate the need for the absolute value?

Comment: Yes, if it is clear from the context that $x\geq 0$, as it should be if $\sqrt{x^3}$ is to make sense.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is just $x\sqrt{x}$, because $x$ could not have been negative, o/w so would the cube be and the square root would then be complex.

Comment: Sorry, I missread the question. For $x\ge 0$ you dont need the absolute value bars because for this case $x=|x|$.

Comment: My book has the answer to: $\sqrt(24x^3y^4)$ as $2abs(x)y^2\sqrt(6x)$

Comment: I guess I don't know how to do absolute value marks in MathJax

Comment: The book is correct, but so is $2xy^2\sqrt{6x}$. It's not wrong to have the absolute value there, it is just not necessary.

Comment: OK, that was very confusing.  This teacher seems to mark off if you don't correctly use the absolute value bars, so this would seem to imply that if I used absolute value bars ALL the time, I'd be safe.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Applying absolute value bars here will ***always*** be fine, assuming $x$ is real.